# Несколько маршрутов на одной карте (Google Maps API)

Tags: google-maps-api

Задача: нанести на одну карту несколько маршрутов, т.е. есть массив, в котором содержаться названия начальных и конечных точек маршрутов, типа такого

```
{"начало"=>"конец"}
{"начало"=>"конец"}
```

и надо проложить и нарисовать все эти маршруты на одной карте.

Я пробовал через `DirectionsRenderer`, но он выдаёт только один маршрут, убирая предыдущий. Подскажите, что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для отрисовки маршрута разные `DirectionsRenderer`. Полный пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var map, directionsService;

            function renderDirections(result, polylineOpts) {
                var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

                if(polylineOpts) {
                    directionsRenderer.setOptions({
                        polylineOptions: polylineOpts
                    });
                }

                directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
            }

            function requestDirections(start, end, polylineOpts) {
                directionsService.route({
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function(result) {
                    renderDirections(result, polylineOpts);
                });
            }

            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -98.35),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),    mapOptions);
                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                requestDirections('New York', "Los Angeles", { strokeColor:'#ff0000' });
                requestDirections('Kansas City', "St. Louis", { strokeColor:'#0000ff' });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    map.setZoom(4);
                }, 2000);

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код будет отстраивать маршруты, не стирая предыдущие

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
    start = document.getElementById("routefrom"),
    end = document.getElementById("routeto");

var request = {origin:start.value, destination:end.value, travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      }
}
```

но это при условии, что вы нигде в коде карту повторно не переинициализировали

Comment: вставил ващь код в свой цикл 
не работает  всервно показывает только 1вый марщрут

Comment: значит, где-то по коду выше переинициализируется карта. в моем приложении интерфейс использкет такой код, чтобы составлять куски маршрутов транспорта с экспортом в маршрутный лист.  
Новые маршруты нормально рисуются в дополнение к старым, только пока с маркерами воюю, пытаюсь штатные А, В сделать нештатными..