# Google maps api Ошибка при нанесении много маршрутов на одной карте

Tags: google-maps-api

В прошлом  вопросе  мне помогли может поможете и сейчас
Используя код  который мне дали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/249235/google-maps-api-google-maps-api-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5) 
я написал следующее

```
  var map2, directionsService2;

        function renderDirections(result, polylineOpts) {
            var directionsRenderer2 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsRenderer2.setMap(map2);

            if(polylineOpts) {
                directionsRenderer2.setOptions({
                    polylineOptions: polylineOpts
                });
            }

            directionsRenderer2.setDirections(result);
        }

        function requestDirections(start, end, polylineOpts) {
            directionsService2.route({
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function(result) {
                renderDirections(result, polylineOpts);
            });
        }

        function initialize2() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.76, 37.64),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'),    mapOptions);
            directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
$.ajax({
            url: "auto_data_JS.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(i){                    
       for( var n in i )
{
    for(var k in i[n]){

 requestDirections(n, i[n][k], { strokeColor:'#ff0000' });
    }}; },
            error: function(i){

                      }
        })


        }

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize2);
```

сначала вроде все работает и маршруты определяютсяи нанносятся на карту
но в какой то момент а консоли появляется ошибка

```
Uncaught Error: Ошибка в информации о собственности <routes>: (Cannot read property 'routes' of null) main.js:16
(anonymous function) main.js:16
(anonymous function) main.js:31
renderDirections auto.php:184
(anonymous function) auto.php:193
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
AT
(anonymous function)
ig main.js:29
uT.(anonymous function).ni
(anonymous function) main.js:29
(anonymous function) main.js:29
M main.js:13
eg main.js:29
jg main.js:29
(anonymous function)
fg.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) main.js:29
(anonymous function) main.js:14
(anonymous function) main.js:29
M main.js:13
(anonymous function) main.js:29
bg.(anonymous function).jf main.js:28
cg.(anonymous function).dd main.js:29
gg main.js:29
(anonymous function) %7Bgeometry,directions%7D.js:2
```

и дальше ничего не чертится
подскажиет что не так
да может это важно - маршрутов в цикле больше сотни

Answer (score 1):

у гугля есть ограничения на использование сервиса маршрутизации - вроде как 150 запросов в сутки с одного хоста.
Если у вас маршруты статичные - парсите ответы сервиса маршрутизации в базу и отдавайте результат уже оттуда.